# Voltage Regulation

Tags: voltage-regulator, driver, opto-isolator, voltage-measurement

I am a young engineer and I need a help from you.

I  need to design a driver circuit which must power-up a LED (OC) if the measured volatge is greater that 50V (Voltage to be measured can be upto 450V DC). The driver must take power from the measurement point.

[image]

As show in the circuit I put a voltage divider and voltage reference(**TL**) will be activated when the measured voltage is greater than 50V and it will drive the transistor which is gonna power up the LED.

The problem lies on the power supply to the transistor I need to have a collector Emitter volatge which can be used for LED power Up. So I put a zener diode regulation circuit (Break down volatge is according to the driver volatge requirment).

I want to make sure this is the perfect solution, is there any other feasible way to do this?. ( Because **R13** is huge in power , is there any other way to limit the power requirment for this?- I need 2mA to drive the LED.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does it run from AC or DC?

Comment: I think the op should answer this.

Comment: Its on DC... I just used here the AC Source just for the testing purpose. So that I can Simulate my threshold (50V) voltage

Comment: So you are measuring (up to 450V) DC and all your circuit is DC powered too?

Comment: yes it is 100 percent DC

Comment: So,  when you probe the measurement point, if the voltage across the probes is anywhere between 50 volts and 450 volts, DC,  the LED should light up and all of the power to make that happen should come from the circuit being probed?

Comment: You are Correct... Thats how I it has to happen. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggestion:

Put in a 2mA current source similar to the schematic below (you would want to adjust the resistor values and pick the appropriate transistors).

Use the TL431 to directly switch on the LED.

Looks like you can modify the R2+R3 path and use that to turn on the TL431.

Add a zener diode from anode of LED to ground to protect the TL431.

Then the total power dissipation is around 450V * 2mA = 0.9W plus the power  through the R2+R3 path.

[image]

Comment: I will try this... I will post soon about the results